# Perform async continuous reading from TcpClient

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, tcpclient, streamreader

I'm trying to read from a remote server using `TcpClient` and I want to so this async. 
I have created a standard `Forms.Timer` that ticks every second and call a function with polls from the server.

I am able to read from the server, i.e, I do manage to see values inside my `buffer`

but for some reason, i'm getting(im guessing after the 5 seconds from the `Delay)`

> this operation is not allowed on non connected sockets

this is my connection to server function

```
        public static async Task<string> readFromPLC()
        {

            using (var client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient())
            {               
                Task connectTask =  client.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, port);
                Task timeoutTask = Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay: 5000);

                if (await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, timeoutTask) == timeoutTask)
                {
                  //  throw new TimeoutException("could not connect to the PLC");
                }

                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
                {                   
                    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
                    while ((await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        sb.Append(String.Join("", buffer));
                    }
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is my timer function

```
        private async void readFromPLCTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string res = String.Empty;
            bool plcStatus = false;
            try
            {
                res = await PLCHelper.readFromPLC();
                plcStatus = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                res = ex.Message;
            }
            setPLCstatus(plcStatus);
            latestCommandTxtBox.AddLine(res);
        }
```

Comment: You never await the `connectTask`. As a result you'll never be able to see any problems with connecting. Do `await connectTask` before you actually start using the `client`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it is awaited on the `Task.WhenAny()`... however no exceptions are caught at all

Comment: @JeroenMostert adding `await connectTask;` before ;`Task.WhenAn();` said gave me "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond". Also [Task.WhenAny()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete) shouldn't have done that?

Comment: @Jcl: No -- `Task.WhenAny` creates a new task that completes if any of the other tasks complete, and that's the task that gets awaited. `WhenAny` itself will never fault.

Comment: @styx: well there you go, the connection failed... not something the code can fix. See if you're Doing it Right -- for example, you now make one single connection, read a line, then close it and do it all over again. The other side may be expecting you to keep the connection open instead.

Comment: @JeroenMostert also to be clear i do have a regular and normal ping to the server

Comment: observation: if you're trying to do async socket work at any non-trivial level, "pipelines" is probably a **much** better model, being designed for this scenario *and* being designed to have a better API for framing and parsing, etc; if this is just a simple socket tool, then it won't matter, of course

Comment: @JeroenMostert oh yes, you'd have to check the original task's `Faulted` and `Exception` there, but still, no such checking is done at all

Comment: @Jcl: hence my advice to `await` the task afterwards, which takes care of that implicitly. This task would not be expected to fail, so I wouldn't write code to check the exception explicitly instead of just handling it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert so what should i do?

Comment: @JeroenMostert you'd be missing the timeout then (afaik TcpClient doesn't have a configurable timeout)... it has its pros and cons... but yes, I definitely get what you mean.

Comment: @styx check if `connectTask` has failed... how you do that, depends on you (you either await the task with a `try/catch` block, or check if the task is faulted and has an exception), and handle the errors

Comment: @Jcl: I'm not suggesting to remove the `WhenAny` -- I'm suggesting to await the task after the `WhenAny` has completed and we've determined that the timeout task wasn't the completed one. Either this completes immediately, or it throws immediately.

Comment: @JeroenMostert gotcha, honest question though: how'd you compare awaiting over a try/catch block there vs just checking `Faulted` and (if it is), throw the `Exception`? What advantage would you give to that? (I'm curious, not saying it wouldn't work)

Comment: Tried all of the above but I'm still getting "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond " I do have a ping to my server

Comment: also when the server sends a command i do get it and able to read it normally

Comment: @Jcl: never rethrow an exception if you can help it; it futzes up the stack trace. There's workarounds for that (and in fact those are exactly used by `async`/`await`), but unless you're deep in some async hole where you have to store the exception away yourself for later processing, prefer having it be thrown directly. (In this *particular* method, it's not that important because we don't really care for the stack trace -- all we need is the socket error message and we could leave out the stack altogether.)

Comment: It's not the same error as that you provided in the question and it most likely indicates some networking problems.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ok, I get your rationale (and actually agree with it). Thanks

Comment: Btw, ping uses ICMP protocol, so it's mostly unrelated to TCP connectivity issues apart from the fact that routing between these 2 peers is working.

Comment: @styx: For connection errors, check your firewall on the destination machine. If the problem isn't obvious, ensure you can duplicate it using Postman.